# Increase font size in Chrome console

Tags: google-chrome, console, font-size

How can I increase the font size in the Chrome console?

It seems Paul Irish did it:

[image]

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mf_yNLlgic)

#### Update:

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150525105431/https://plus.google.com/+AddyOsmani/posts/UZF34wPJXsL) are some tips on how to customize Chrome developer tools.

Comment: Unfortunately, <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd> to zoom is not the same as changing browser font-size. You're actually zooming in the entire page. It would be nice to have an easy way to test users with different appearance settings, for say if you are using REMs everywhere and need to test breakpoints.

Answer (score 259, accepted):

If you just need a quick, temporary size bump you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> / <kbd>-</kbd> to zoom and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> to reset.

Comment: I had no idea this would work in the console independent of the web page.  Nice one...

Comment: For mac users: **⌘+** and **⌘-**

Comment: How to set custom zoom? Not predefined + | -

Comment: +1 The zoom shortcuts (as well as other nifty keyboard shortcuts) are documented at https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/shortcuts#global-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: Thank the lord someone posted this. I did an accidental keystroke and increased this size, and then found no way to get it back until I stumbled across this post.

Comment: This does not work for me on Mac, ⌘+ switches to the first tab instead (even when I disabled it by unchecking `Enable ⌘ + 1-9 shortcut to switch panels`).

Comment: `Ctrl 0` worked for me. I am using Mac. `Ctrl +` only zooms in the main view and not the dev tools. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works for Microsoft Edge console as well.

Comment: @jcalfee314 I feel suddenly smarter :D

Comment: I have turkish QWERTY keyboard and CMD+"+" doesn't work for me. CMD+"+" just selects the fourth tab on Chrome. However, CMD+"-" and CMD+"0" works as normal. I couldn't find any way to change it, even with a mouse.

Comment: On any advanced (international) keyboard (where + is not mapped directly) use ⌘-0 (+ does not work)

Answer (score 24):

Here's a pretty recent [blog post](http://blog.dotsmart.net/2011/09/30/change-font-size-in-chrome-devtools/) on the subject.

Basically, override `Default/User StyleSheets/Custom.css` in your [user directory](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md) with something like:

```
/* Keep .platform-mac to make the rule more specific than the general one above. */
body.platform-mac.platform-mac-snowleopard .monospace,
body.platform-mac.platform-mac-snowleopard .source-code {
    font-size: 11px !important;
    font-family: Menlo, monospace;
}

body.platform-windows .monospace, body.platform-windows .source-code {
    font-size: 12px !important;
    font-family: Consolas, Lucida Console, monospace;
}

body.platform-linux .monospace, body.platform-linux .source-code {
    font-size: 11px !important;
    font-family: dejavu sans mono, monospace;
}
```

Comment: FYI, this doesn't do anything about the font size in the console, as far as I can tell.  It's great for things like the source code pane, but the console itself seems to have very specific settings for many things that override the font-size settings here.

Comment: @Boris Smus There is no `User StyleSheets/Custom.css` folder/file in my `C:\Users\c22\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` directory on my Windows 8 laptop. And I've checked all the folders and files in the `Default` directory.  This question is over a year ago, has anyone found where the `custom.css` file is located in Chrome 37.0.x?

Thanks

Comment: Custom Stylesheet is removed from Chromium : https://codereview.chromium.org/66383005/ . If you want to custom your theme, try using a Chrome devtools extension: https://github.com/mauricecruz/zero-base-themes

Comment: downvote simply because this may have been a great tip once, but it is no longer valid.

Answer (score 22):

1. Open Browser
2. Open Console.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>.

I hope it will help you

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? As it stands, it's not really a clear answer.

Comment: It is really more easy way than chosen as answer for this question.

Comment: For mac users:  **⌘-** and **⌘+**

Comment: This has the undesirable side-effect of zooming all the other UI elements as well and effectively decreasing total available reading space.

Answer (score 14):

If you are on a Mac, are using a japanese keyboard, and want to zoom the console temporarily, the short-cuts are:

Zoom In: <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>^</kbd>

Zoom Out: <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd>

Reset Zoom: <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>

Other Applications are using <kbd>+</kbd> for zooming in, but because on japanese keyboards the plus-sign is on the second level, it is only accessible with shift. So: <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd>

That where it gets weird, because to Chrome <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> apparently means "Zoom Content". If you are in the Javascript console, and do <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd>, the window's content area in zoomed in. But doing a Zoom-out <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> moves the focus back to the console and zooms it out. Result: The content is getting larger, the console smaller. *Aaarggghhh*.

Comment: saved my day! gosh how i  hate japanese keyboards

Answer (score 9):

Windows 7, Google Chrome 19.0.1084.46 m

Method with modifying "User StyleSheets/Custom.css" not worked on me, but Ctrl+"+" worked :-)

Comment: I dont know why i didnt try this.... der... thanks... 

Would like to change the font though...

Answer (score 8):

**THIS IS OBSOLETE - See @TinyJaguar's answer.  You can now just use Command-+ if you've selected something in the developer console.**

If you want to increase the font size in the Javascript console, you need some specific font sizes.  It's a bit trickier than just setting the font size for source:

```
.source-code {
    font-size: 16px !important;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.console-prompt {
    font-size: 16px !important;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.console-message-text {
    font-size: 16px !important;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.monospace {
    font-size: 16px !important;
    font-family: monospace;
}

#elements-content {
  font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

Comment: This works. The CSS in the OP-selected answer does not (anymore, at least).

Comment: where would you put this css?

Comment: @ChrisRedford yes, where does this code go?  I don't have the `C:\Users\c22\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User Stylesheet\Custom.css` file in windows 8.

Comment: @Chris22 Sorry, this is a problem I had almost a year ago. I don't remember what files were involved and I'm not developing closely with web browsers anymore.

Comment: @ChrisRedford ok, thanks for replying.  I'll use the quick fix of ctrl +/-.  Chrome has made it very difficult to find the CSS file to edit on purpose, I suppose.

Comment: Note: this worked for me, but not in the Console, I had to select the Elements tab of dev tools first

Answer (score 7):

Of Note: From within DevTools, you must have the Elements Tab open in order to adjust font size by using "Ctrl +/-."  For some reason it cannot be done in other tabs.

In the newer version of Chrome, you can easily change the font size of font in Developer Tools.

1. Open Developer Tools
2. Click on any line in source code
   [image: Clicking random line on source code]
3. Press Ctrl + + to increase font size or Ctrl + - to decrease font size
   [image: Pressing required key combinations to increase or decrease font size]

Comment: It's predefined zoom. How about to set custom zoom?

Answer (score 7):

On MacOs, if your key <kbd>0</kbd> or <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd> are on the second level, typing <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> won't work. In such a case, you need to use capslock <kbd>⇪</kbd>, and then you can type <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>

Answer (score 6):

I've created a small plugin which provides a collection editor settings for Chrome Developer Tools, **including the ability to incrementally control font size**.

1. Install [DevTools Author Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/devtools-author/egfhcfdfnajldliefpdoaojgahefjhhi) from Chrome Web Store
2. Enable Developer Tools experiments in chrome://flags/#enable-devtools-experiments. Restart Chrome for
   flags to take effect.
3. Open DevTools (cmd + opt + I); Settings > Experiments > check Allow custom UI themes.

This will add an 'Author Settings' panel to Chrome Developer Tools, where you can incrementally control font size, from 10px - 22px

Answer (score 6):

If you're like me, <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> is not working for you because it switches you to the first tab instead (even though you have `Enable ⌘ + 1-9 shortcut to switch panels` turned off).

Well, in that case, open Dev Tools, `Undock into separate window` and then go for `View --> Zoom in` in Chrome Menu Bar. Voilà!

Once you dock Dev Tools back into the browser window, `View --> Zoom in` will actually increase font size in a browser window, but as long as Dev Tools are undocked, it targets the undocked Dev Tools.

Comment: You saved my eyes.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 6):

Press

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to zoom **in**
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to zoom **out**
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to reset to default

For Mac, replace <kbd>CTRL</kbd> with <kbd>CMD</kbd> key (a.k.a., <kbd>⌘</kbd>).

Answer (score 3):

I know this is way old, but the simple solution I found is to increase the `min. font size` in the settings and that will take care of the font size in chrome debugger.

Answer (score 3):

Another quick way to change the font size in Chrome Dev tools permanently: `Settings`--> `Show Advanced Settings` --> `Web Content` : change the Page Zoom percentage.

[image: Change font size]

**Here is the result:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHM0P.png
[image: Size by size comparison]

Comment: Does it affect Chrome system-wide or only for DevTools?

Comment: It changed Chrome system-wide font size.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a newer MacBook pro 2017, you can simply use command => shift => + or -  all pressed at once.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a laptop, you can do that with only your laptop trackpad.

Tap on your trackpad with one finger(don't release yet) then scroll up or down with another finger to increase or decrease font size.

Just make sure the dev tools panel is on focus.
Tested and working on my HP Pavilion, Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

press ctrl and hover your mouse wheel

Answer (score 0):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>+ / -</kbd> to zoom and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> to reset Console font size.

You can see all available shortcuts Chrome's Console in the settings.

<kbd>F12</kbd> (open dev tools) -> <kbd>F1</kbd> -> Shortcuts

[** Chrome shortcuts **](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvCyj.jpg)